# Table Does Not Exist while using .NET 6 and Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 6.21.5

Tags: c#, oracle, razor, .net-6.0

I am trying out Razor and Core for the first time and just want to connect to our oracle DB and bring back data.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> OracleException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(out int cursorId, bool bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, int arrayBindCount, ref OracleException exceptionForArrayBindDML, out bool hasMoreRowsInDB, bool bFirstIterationDone)*

**ModelContext.cs snippet**

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("TRADMIN")
                .UseCollation("USING_NLS_COMP");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Agency>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("AGENCY");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.Description, "IX_DESCRIPTION")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnName("ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                    .HasMaxLength(250)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("DESCRIPTION");

                entity.Property(e => e.InactiveDate)
                    .HasColumnType("DATE")
                    .HasColumnName("INACTIVE_DATE");
            });
```

**Tried setting the default schema just in case it was a schema problem the following way in the Data folder DbContext file and it did not make a difference**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //set a default schema for all tables
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("tradmin");
        }
```

**Debug Console**

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (83ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
      SELECT "a"."Id", "a"."Description", "a"."InactiveDate"
      FROM "Agency" "a"
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[0]
      2022-03-29 14:35:38.690640 ThreadID:12  (ERROR)   OracleExecutionStrategy.Execute() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

**appsettings.json snippet**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DevConnection": "User Id=*****;Password=*****; Data Source=****;"
    }
```

**Program.cs snippet**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SDD_Training.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseOracle(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")
    )); ;

var app = builder.Build();
```

**ApplicationDBContext.cs snippet**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SDD_Training.Models;

namespace SDD_Training.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Agency> Agency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**models\Agency.cs snippet**

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SDD_Training.Models

{

    public partial class Agency

    {

        public decimal Id { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime? InactiveDate { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**agency\index.cshtml.cs snippet**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

using SDD_Training.Data;

using SDD_Training.Models;

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SDD_Training.Pages.agencies;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDBContext _db;

    public IEnumerable<Agency> Agency { get; set; }


    public IndexModel(ApplicationDBContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Agency = _db.Agency;   
    }
}
```

**agency/index.cshtml snippet**

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Agency Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Inactive Date
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var obj in Model.Agency)
            {
            <tr>
                <td width="10%">
                    @obj.Id
                </td>
                <td width="50%">
                    @obj.Description
                </td>
                <td width="40%">
                    @obj.InactiveDate
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Agency Table I am trying to display**

[image]

Comment: What did you discover when you googled "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"?  The very existence of that error means you successfully connected to the database.  By far the most common cause of that error is that you are connected as a user that is different from the owner of the table, and you did not qualify the table name with the owner, specifying only the table name, like 'select * from emp', when you should qualify it, like 'select * from scott.emp.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated ticket showing schema information for the ModelContext.cs and manually trying to set it in the dbcontext.cs section. It did not resolve my issue.

Comment: In your model class for Agency, try adding an attribute like `[Table("SCOTT.EMP")]`.  I use this to force the schema.  It needs to go above the class definition, under the namespace.

Comment: I added it as you stated and now it shows the schema twice in the error.                                                                                                   
 fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      
      SELECT "t"."Id", "t"."Description", "t"."InactiveDate"
      FROM **"tradmin"."tradmin.Agency"** "t"
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[0]
      2022-03-30 10:52:46.662107 ThreadID:6   (ERROR)   OracleExecutionStrategy.Execute() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00942: table or view does not